# question about commutative and associate law

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

[image]

> I knew the definition of the commutative and associate law but i don't understand how the commutative and associate law transform these conditional statement.

Comment: Apply them step-by-step: first [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Rule_of_replacement) to $(\lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor (p \lor q)$ to get $[(\lnot p) \lor (p \lor q)] \land [(\lnot q) \lor (p \lor q)]$.

Comment: Then Associativity abd Commutativity to get : $[(¬p∨p) ∨ q)] ∧ [(¬q∨q) ∨ p)] \equiv (q \land p)$

Comment: it also need distributive law